# Problem with mysql trying to Select from values of certain CHAR_LENGTH and Order by DESC

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

Hello so in my database I have some player info.
It saves their info under two UID's but their wallet is the same value.

My current query just takes both uids and places them on my list. I have been searching for a while and cannot find a way to make my query discard characters of more than 10 in length.

I really desperately need help. I'm exhausted.

**Current Query:**

```
$query = "SELECT rpname, wallet FROM darkrp_player ORDER by wallet DESC LIMIT 20";
```

**What I would like it to be:**

```
$query = "SELECT CHAR_LENGTH(uid)10>, rpname, wallet FROM darkrp_player ORDER by wallet DESC LIMIT 20";
```

Basically I'm trying to only return `UID` of character length = 10

Thank you in advance guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 SELECT uid, rpname, wallet FROM darkrp_player 
WHERE LENGTH(uid) = 10 ORDER by wallet DESC LIMIT 20
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to return the 10 leftmost 10 characters of the `uid` value you can use [`LEFT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_left):

```
SELECT LEFT(uid, 10) AS uid, rpname, wallet 
FROM darkrp_player 
ORDER by wallet DESC 
LIMIT 20
```

If you want to ignore `uid` values longer than 10 characters, you can use a `WHERE` clause on the [`LENGTH`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_length) of the `uid`:

```
SELECT uid, rpname, wallet 
FROM darkrp_player 
WHERE LENGTH(uid) <= 10
ORDER by wallet DESC 
LIMIT 20
```